# How can we calculate staking rewards per epoch?

Tags: wallet, staking, rewards

Deadalus shows total staking rewards for a wallet.  IIRC, there is a planned feature to show staking rewards per epoch for a wallet.

How we can calculate staking rewards per epoch for a wallet right now?

Comment: Should one of the answers be marked as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the per-epoch rewards on https://adapools.org, example:
https://adapools.org/stake/stake1u94cewwzweul0z7e73462fjgextms4vge44y0f0d0a6rfjgj802t9

[Yoroi](https://yoroi-wallet.com/) does show per-epoch rewards too.

Answer (score 0):

Our alliance website has a calculator.

https://armada-alliance.com/

We are an alliance of single pools who run on decentralized bare metal low powered arm devices. Please do not stake with pool splitters or pools located in centralized datacenters.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by using the Cardano's Official [calculator tool](https://cardano.org/calculator/?calculator=delegator), using advanced options you can enter the information about the pool that you are staking to and see the estimated rewards. Without advanced options it's just an esteem and results can be a little bit different from what you will receive at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I also created a calculator which shows Operator and Delegator (SUM) rewards per Epoch and Month based on the given Network and Pool Parameters.

You can find it here: (Download if you want to change inputs)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ztm6Jov85Vk7AGtZ22BVE3I-BhzIlubnLSTUEomdq4U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

To make it more easy to use I created a Version of the Calculation sheet which includes calculation for an individual delegator.

Here is the new Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a2fqlM66wHNAJkRyLFhY8gaJPmwgnL7glx-NewOywdw/edit?usp=sharing

Just fill out the colored cells with the Pools and delegators details you want to use for your calculation and see the results below (Cell B20 and B21)

This calculation considers:

- Current Block Rewards (will get lower over time)
- Pool Pledge
- Pool Fixed Cost
- Pool Margin
- Poisson Distribution to consider Luck

This calculation does NOT consider

- Risk of battles (slot or height battles) - Bigger Pools lose more blocks to battles which decreases the Average Rewards (by up to 10% at a fully saturated pool, depending on network congestion)